# How can I get the screen position of content on the page?

Tags: javascript, dom

The `window.screenX` and `window.screenY` properties only give the top left corner of the *outer window*, outside the content area (above the address bar and tabs).

How can I determine the position of the inner content area of the window (below the address bar)? It looks like Firefox has a [window.mozInnerScreenX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.mozInnerScreenX) property- is there no way to calculate this value in Chrome or other browsers?